# Using postgresql with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I keep getting this error in the web page

Using postgresql.
pgadmin 4

Unauthorized
The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

settings.py

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
            'USER': env('DB_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'HOST': env('DB_HOST'), 
            'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
        }
    }
```

What can i do to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you did wrong in database in settings.py file. You should use `os.environ.get` instead of `env`.

Change this:

```
'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
```

To this:

```
'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
```

Comment: I don't think so. I tired running a django project that does not use postgresql as its database but sill the same error message in the browser